# Does "very non-extensive" quantum matter exist?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, entropy

This is a two-fold question:

1. I have read that the entropy of a black hole is proportional to its surface area.
   It left me wondering if it is possible to create some (non-trivial) quantum matter with such property: its entropy is possibly not additive, only depends on its surface area? (or at least to create some matter that is **very** non-extensive?$^\dagger$ )
2. I was thinking of a super thick "bubble" with a vacuum inside, however, I am not sure about the multiplicity of a vacuum quantum state, so I am left more confused.

---

$^\dagger$I know entropy is not *exactly* extensive, but that can always be ignored when the particle number is large enough.

Comment: From a microscopic point-of-view the extensiveness of the entropy commes from the fact that you can factorize the partition function into products of different phase space regions. Most condensed-matter interactions are short-range by nature or by screening phenomena, and that is why you can discard surface terms in the thermodynamical limit. But gravity cannot be screened, so even in newtonian gravity you would expect non-extensive entropy, even in the thermodynamic limit. So Earth's entropy contains non-extensive terms already, nevermind black-holes.